# Python, Pygame, Livewires - How to make smooth collisions?

Tags: python, pygame, collision, livewires

```
for spike in self.overlapping_sprites:
    spike.handle_collide
```

These two lines are coding magic for beginners. However, I seem to have hit a brick wall in my games. After testing around I cannot find a way to make collisions more *Precise!* What I mean is that it's not when two sprites actually touch that they count as overlapping, it's when the boxes around them overlap. So how can I somehow make it so that the transparent area  around my sprite doesn't count as a collision if it hits other sprites?

Answer (score 1):

The most logical thing to do is to make two rectangles per sprite, outer one with borders and inner one counted as object itself.

Take a 64 x 64 box for example. You can make it like 62 x 62 inner box with 2 pixel margin, shouldn't be too difficult to implement. And check only the inner area for collision if you want area nearby box to be untouchable.